# How do I switch tabs when using iTerm2 with Z shell

Tags: iterm, zsh

How do I switch tabs when using Z shell on iTerm2? I have already tried all the possible key combinations. Here is an image of my current setup:

[image]

OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4 (18E226)

iTerm2: Build 3.3.0beta7

Key combos tried: Different combinations of <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>}</kbd>, <kbd>{</kbd> keys.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to apple.stackexchange @ibp73. Could you please add some more information to your question, such as what version of macOS and iTerm2 you're currently using, and also (if possible) a list of key combinations you've tried?

Comment: @Sam - I have updated the question.

Answer (score 17):

Use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to switch to next and previous tabs respectively. The same are also available under iTerm2 Menu Bar → Window menu.

[image]

The keyboard shortcuts remain the same irrespective of the shell you are running.

Answer (score 7):

You can view/update current key bindings if you open the Preference window from the menu bar `iTerm2 > Preferences > Keys > Key Bindings`

For me, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> as well as <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>]</kbd> (as mentioned by previous answer) work by default.

I am using iTerm2 (3.3.7) on macOS Catalina (10.15.2)

Answer (score 4):

On the trackpad: two-finger swipe, left and right will scroll through the tabs.

On the keyboard:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> (scroll left)

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> (scroll right)

The keyboard commands loop through tabs, whereas the trackpad gesture does not.

Answer (score 2):

Latest iTerm2

From my end:
OS: macOS Monterey (version 12.3.1)
iTerm2 (Build 3.4.15)

Use the keyboard shortcuts

`Command + ]`

`Command + [`

to switch to the next and previous tabs respectively